# Is it possible to call a function after typing each keyword in ace-editor

Tags: callback, keyword, ace-editor

What I want to do is that in ace-editor, each time when I finished typing a keyword, a function can be called automatically.

For example, I TYPE the keyword "new" in ace-editor. After I finished typing, an alert function will be called and say "you have typed the keyword 'new'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use change listener or beforeEndOperation listener, and use something like

```
editor.on("beforeEndOperation", function(e) {
    if (editor.curOp.docChanged && editor.curOp.command.name == "insertstring") {
        var pos = editor.getCursorPosition();
        var token = editor.session.getTokenAt(pos.row, pos.column);
        if (token && token.type == "keyword") {
            alert(
                "Hey there!", 
                "This is me, the most annoying editor feature evar.",
                "Just wanted to let you know, that you have typed a keyword",
                token.value
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Your solution is almost right, but there is  an issue need to be fixed: When I insert a keyword among strings, it doesn't work.  For example, I insert "new" in a string "hello" --- "henewllo", and enter the whitespace --- "he new llo", now the "new" should be a keyword, but it doesn't work... Do you have any idea about it?  Thanks again.

Comment: When entering whitespace the token at cursor will be whitespace, you could also check the token at column-1

Comment: Yes, but it will cause another issue --- after typing "new", it will trigger the alert function, and then you enter two whitespaces, and backspace one whitespace, it will trigger the alert function again.

Comment: `editor.curOp.command.name == "insertstring"` makes sure alert is called only after inserting text

Comment: Thank you! I solved the issue about whitespace I mentioned before, but if we enter "Tab" or "Enter", how do we check the token, it is not in column-1.